# How to duplicate values from Cell to Cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to duplicate the n values from the column A to Column B

Example:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. That is indeed doable in VBA. A simple loop can give you what you want. But show us what you've tried. Also, what if there are already duplicate values in Column A? Does it matter?

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic or is always A to B? If B has data should it clear it ? Can A have blanks?

Comment: Does not need to be dynamic. The data of B should be cleared. A should not have blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-volatile option:

```
=INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2)+1)
```

(Offset will cause a recalculation of all sheets whenever any cell changes)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this.

Divide the row number minus 1 by 2, int it (chop off decimals as opposed to rounding), finally use that as an offset reference.

```
=OFFSET(A$1,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2),0)
```

Drag down